# Unity game for SDK Facebook error

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I opened this sample project here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/tutorials/games/

and I got the following error:

Assets/Scripts/MainMenu.cs(24,12): error CS0117: `FB' does not contain a definition for`GetAuthResponse'

For it, Could anybody help me to fix it?
Thanks in advance
Alejandro Castan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing that out.  The newest SDK eliminated the need for GetAuthResponse and we are in the process of updating the example code to reflect that.  For now you can do this:

Delete the line:

```
FB.GetAuthResponse(LoginCallback);
```

and replace it with:

```
if(FB.IsLoggedIn) {
  LoginCallback(new Facebook.FBResult(""));
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian Jew,First of all, thanks for your help. I could fix this error but since my English is little  I could not deploy the game (both Client.html and Client.unity3d files) in the server, for it, and sorry for my ignorance but Where I should to upload these files? Is there any special server to do it? Could I use filezilla to deploy the game in this server?
Thanks for your help 
Best Regards
Alejandro

Comment: Any server that can do a https protocol should work.  If you don't have one, you can look into Parse: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide  They are able to host unity games.

Answer (score 0):

The project just got updated and the problem has been solved.